# AWS S3 replication without versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have enabled AWS S3 replication in an account and I want to replicate the same S3 data to another account and it all works fine. But I don't want to use S3 versioning because of its additional cost.

So is there any other way to accommodate this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The automated *Same Region Replication(SRR)* and *Cross Region Replication(CRR)* requires versioning to be activated due to the way that data is replicated between S3 buckets. For example, a new version of an object might be uploaded while a bucket is still being replicated, which can lead to problems without having separate versions.

If you do not wish to retain other versions, you can configure **Amazon S3 Lifecycle Rules** to expire (delete) older versions.

An alternative method would be to run the AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command at regular intervals to copy the data between buckets. This command would need to be run on an Amazon EC2 instance or even your own computer. It could be triggered by a cron schedule (Linux) or a Schedule Task (Windows).

Comment: Note that lifecycle rules to delete old files WILL NOT DELETE OLD VERSIONS.  This can get very expensive in large buckets as they steadily bloat over time.